# SQL Server 2014 - Missing option on Replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151192.aspx) details exact steps to set up basic database replication with SQL Server 2014.

It starts with this:

> 2. Right-click the Replication folder, and then click Configure Distribution.

On right clicking my Replication folder (I do believe I installed replication), I only get the following options:

```
Launch Replication Monitor
Generate Scripts....
Update Replication Passwords...
```

I can't find any other place in SQL Server Mgmt Studio to get to this section. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the Express edition?

Comment: Yeah - just noticed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. Was using express version of trial. I thought, as it was a trial, it would at least let me try all features.

Downloaded the Enterprise 6-month trial edition instead. This should work.

#### Update

Yeah, it works now.